# Locked out of an old company Mac mini

Tags: recovery

I'm locked out of an old Mac mini and would like to be able to use it. Completely new to the world of Mac so hoping someone more experienced can help...

The device was made in 2011 (or so I'm told by apple) and it has been in our company since not long after. It was setup by some guys a while ago who have probably left the company but we can't identify. It has a hardware encryption password (tpm?) which we don't know. We do not know the credentials to login to the machine and probably have no realistic prospect of recovering them. Our inventory does not list the item because it was purchased and claimed on expenses (most likely to cut down lead times) so we cannot track former users.

Apple say our only remaining option is to recover the passwords or to use some third party to recover it. I'd like to know what's on it but that's not hugely important (only interested as I'd like to know who set it up). Is there a way to recover or reformat this machine? Command R on boot prompts for a password which we do not have.

Comment: I assume you are talking about a Firmware Password? If so, have you googled how to remove it?

Comment: I'm not sure of the technical term but I guess a firmware password fits the bill. In terms of Googling, yes, but the results mostly specify the same thing about removing RAM - a trick which didn't work for me. Whatever I do, it wants either the firmware password or shows the login screen (with the 2 accounts, me not knowing either password).

Comment: if the RAM trick does not work, I'm afraid there are no other options.

Comment: Do you know if the encryption is forced by a TPM or is loaded by firmware on a chip? I wonder if there may be a way to reprogram that chip or even outright remove the TPM?

Comment: not sure what a TPM is but there is no way around it other than contacting Apple, and showing proof-of-purchase.

Comment: You can boot into the CLI and create a new administrator account. Then you can try to remove any passwords set.

Comment: TPM stands for "Trusted Platform Module". It generates and stores the encryption keys for encrypting the hard drive. However, I thought Macs don't have TPM chips?

Comment: AFAIR Apple's 2011 models don't contain a TPM (Trusted Platform Module) and never published drivers for the Macs containing one. Instead of guessing simply take pictures of all password protected log-in windows/password fields (Recovery Mode/normal start-up) and add them to your question!

Comment: It's the mid-2011 model according to the serial, although people in the office claim it hasn't been booted in 5 years (meaning it would've been bought, chucked in a box within a couple months, and left for dead). I know TPM is the Windows version, looks like the Apple version is some onboard thing. Looks like changing the hard drive isn't an option since it's on the motherboard (logic board? IDK what it's called, it'll always be a motherboard to me!) If there are any less official suggestions please fire away. Unless I get a late email reply, I'm looking at a £700 paperweight.

Comment: I also do know people who would be both capable of and willing to remove components from the board, so if the security chip can be bypassed in that sort of way, it would also be appreciated. We're on a science park, and the people here are always helping one another out :)

Comment: Is there a reason this can't be option-booted and booted from a USB installation stick of OS X to format the drive? Or to have the HDD swapped out?

Comment: The firmware password prevents selection of a boot device, same reason I can't just switch out the HDD. Apple claim the only thing this machine will let you do is enter a password...